# Getting notified of deserialization of a subclass within that class

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a logging system for objects of a specific type.

I am storing them in a `WeakHashMap` inside of a static method of a different class. This way I can monitor their changes without influencing when they are constructed/deconstructed. The one issue with this is that these objects are serializable and will FREQUENTLY be serialized/deserialized.

To add some more detail the class in question is a subtype of a class that is defined inside of a framework. The subclass is serialized/deserialized inside of this framework so I have no way of changing this behavior from the superclass (because that code is in the framework). For some reason one does not have to implement deserialization on the sub class and it is handled automatically by the framework.

The problem is while I can log object like so

```
public abstract class Thing implements Serializable {
// This classes definition and declaration lives inside of a framework
}
public class ClassIWantToLog extends Thing {
   public ClassIWantToLog(/*ARGS*/) {
     super(/*ARGS*/
     /*Things with this*/
     StaticToolsClass.logWithWeakReference(this);
   }
}
```

If that object is ever serialized than deserialized I loose the reference so it is removed from my `WeakHashMap` and when it is recreated this constructor is not called so I cant re-add it to my `WeakHashMap`.

The goal would be to somehow override a method that will automatically be called inside of `ClassIWantToLog` when it is deserialized so I can pass that new object to `StaticToolsClass`.

I am willing to use reflection if that is necessary and if at all possible hopefully overriding said method would not add too much code (ex: I don't want to have to implement custom deserialization as well).

Comment: Just add a `private static Object readObject()` method as per the Serialization Specification that calls `in.defaultReadObject()` to get the serializarion done and then does whatever else you want.

Comment: Or a `readResolve()` method that just does your stuff and then returns `this`.